# Why is yield from native coroutines valid syntax

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-3.3

[PEP-380](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) introduces the `yield from` syntax and says:

```
yield from <expr>
```

where  is an expression evaluating to an iterable, from which an iterator is extracted. So the following are legal and make sense:

1. yield from generators
2. yield from generator_based_coroutine ( that use the `@asyncio.coroutine` decorator)

since both generators and generator based coroutines are instances of Iterable. However, I fail to understand why

```
yield from native_coroutines (using async/await syntax)
```

is legal? Since [PEP-492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/) states that native coroutines don't implement the `__iter__` and `__next__` methods and therefore aren't iterable. However, there's no PEP that talks about this change in behavior of yield from to accept coroutine objects that are returned by native coroutines?

I know generator based coroutines will get deprecated in 3.10 but I still want to know why `yield from` works with native coroutines.

Answer (score 1):

> However, I fail to understand why `yield from native_coroutines` (using async/await syntax)
>   is legal? Since PEP-492 states that native coroutines don't implement the `__iter__` and `__next__` methods and therefore aren't iterable.

However, PEP 492 [also states](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#differences-from-generators) that "*generator-based coroutines* [...] can `yield from` native coroutine objects."

> However, I fail to understand why `yield from native_coroutines` is legal?

Because otherwise native coroutines would not be usable from legacy code that used generator-based coroutines and `yield from`.

For example, at some point after `async def` was introduced, most asyncio primitives, including `asyncio.sleep`, were converted to `async def` coroutines. If those didn't support `yield from`, the conversion would break all existing asyncio code that awaited `asyncio.sleep` using `yield from`, previously the only possible way to await. Such backward incompatibility would have been a show-stopper for introduction of native coroutines, so it was avoided.

Comment: I understand the rationale that you are describing for having native coroutines be yielded from. However, I am looking for authoritative documentation/PIP that describes this behavior.

Comment: @dataCheeku It is described in PEP 492, I've now amended the answer to be explicit about it.